# Cannot POST nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Iam trying to add comment to the blogs on the blog page but i cannot find the error ,I keep getting the error "CANNOT POST /" after clicking the submit button on  the form. What is missing and what's the problem? I tried the code below for my form:

here is my complete .ejs code for that page .
'''

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/user/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2><%=post.title%></h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p><%=post.content%></p>
    </div>
    <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
      <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">
        Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/warning-over-dangerous-diy-beauty-trends-on-tiktok/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small>
      </h3>
      <form method="POST" onsubmit="return doComment(this);">
        <input type=""  name="post_id" value="<%=post._id%>" />
        
        <div class='form-group'>  
          <textarea placeholder="Comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>  
          <input placeholder="Name (required)" name="author" type="text"  required />
        </div>
        
        <div class='form-group'>  
          <input  placeholder="Email (required)" name="email" type="email" required />
        </div>
          <input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" value="Post Comment">
      </form> 

    <script>
       function doComment(form){
          $.ajax({
              url:"/do-comment",
              method:"POST",
              data:{author: form.author.value, 
              comment: form.comment.value, 
              post_id: form.post_id.value,
              email: form.email.value},
              success: function (response){
                  alert(response);
              }
          });
          return false;
        }
    </script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:100px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
   
      <div class="fakeimg"><a href="<%=post._id%>">Image</a></div><br>
  
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me</h3>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%- include('footer'); -%>

</body>
</html>
```

'''

here is my complete .js code i have written :

'''

```
 var express =require("express");
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
app.use("/static",express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended : false
      }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
var MongoClient =require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017",{useUnifiedTopology: true},
    function(error, client){
        var blog=client.db("blog");
        console.log("DB Connected");
        app.get('/', function(req,res) {
            blog.collection("posts").find().sort({"_id":-1}).toArray(function(error,posts){

            res.render("user/home",{posts: posts}) ;
            });
        });
        app.get("/admin/dashboard", function(req,res) {
            res.render("admin/dashboard");
        });
        app.get("/admin/posts", function(req,res) {
            res.render("admin/posts");
        });
        app.post("/do-post",function(req,res){
            blog.collection("posts").insertOne(req.body, function(error, document){
                res.send("posted succesfully");
            });
        });
        app.get("/posts/:id", function(req, res){
            console.log("Comment");
            blog.collection("posts").findOne({"_id": ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function (error, post) {
                res.render("user/post", {post: post});
            });
        });
        app.post("/do-comment", function(req, res){
            blog.collection("posts").update({"_id": ObjectId(req.body.id) }, { 
                $push: { 
                    "comments": {author: req.body.author, comment: req.body.comment, email: req.body.email } 
                }
            }, function (error, post) {
                res.send("comment Sucessfull");
            });
        });
        app.listen(3000, function(){
            console.log("Connected");
        });

    });
```

'''

Comment: There are several things that could be the issue. Please extend your html and js code so we can see the full form including the starting `<form>` tag. 

beside this: 
console log the error case in your `$.ajax` function to investigate the issue.
is your server listening? is there a cors issue?

Comment: okay i have updated the code
' app.post("/do-comment", function(req, res){
            blog.collection("posts").update({"_id": ObjectId(req.body.id) }, { 
                $push: { 
                    "comments": {author: req.body.author, comment: req.body.comment, email: req.body.email } 
                }
            }, function (error, post) {
                res.send("comment Sucessfull");
            });
        });'

Comment: Alright. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36226334/14721231 .
Brian Bolli answer should help you

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help :)

Comment: iam still not able to solve the peoblem :(
iam stock in this Since morning

Comment: Thanks myann i got the error :)